# ios touchesBegan doen't work unless breakpoint is set

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to implement a `CGButton` like in this tutorial:
http://ganbarugames.com/2014/09/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift/

I tried this on a simple test project, and it worked great.
Then I put this in my working project, strange things happened.

When I click on the button, `touchesBegan()` is not called (I checked this by adding a `println` in there). Hence the action is not triggered. However, if I put a breakpoint at any line within the `touchesBegan()`, then this breakpoint is hit and `touchesBegan()` can work after I continue. (e.g. `println()` prints out this time)

I suppose a breakpoint won't affect the flow of the program. What causes this, and how can I fix it?

**Add**:
I add some animations on the button when `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` (scale to 1.1 when began and scale back to original size when ended). It turns out when I tap on the button, the `touchesBegan` animation is triggered(scale to 1.1) but it just stop there, and `println` is not hit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a button or a switch for generic use, you should try this control I made, the use its pretty straight forward:
You just initialize the type of Button/Switch you want (ColoredSprite, Textured or TextOnly)

```
let control = TWButton(normalColor: SKColor.blueColor(), highlightedColor: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 160, height: 80))
```

And after initialize you add a closure to it (like addTargetForSelector on UIButton)

```
 control.addClosureFor(.TouchUpInside, target: self, closure: { (scene, sender) -> () in
            scene.testProperty = "Changed Property"
        })
    }
```

That’s it! There’s more info on the readme section on the GitHub page: https://github.com/txaidw/TWControls

But if you want to implement in a specific node here’s how I did:

```
internal override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)

    if self.containsPoint(touchPoint) {
        self.touchLocationLast = touchPoint
        touchDown()
    }
}

internal override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)
    self.touchLocationLast = touchPoint
}


internal override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)

        if let lastPoint = self.touchLocationLast where self.containsPoint(lastPoint) {
            // Ended inside
            touchUpInside()
        }
        else {
            // Ended outside
            touchUpOutside()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me. My colleague just helped me out here.
So the reason causes this problem is, I have a tap and pan gesture recognizer in my view controller and they conflict with my `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`.

So when I click, first the `touchesBegan` is triggered. but then it goes to tap recognizer instead of my `touchesEnded`. Same thing, when I drag, it goes to pan recognizer instead of `touchesMoved`